# ERROR (glitch in pandas?) : Why when indexes of a pandas.core.series.Series are numbers as strings python can't retrive the its values?

Tags: python, pandas, series, keyerror

I'm going to the grain. Every one knows that a column, say `col = df['field']` is a 'pandas.core.series.Series'. And also `counts = df['field'].value_counts()` with the method `value_counts()` is a 'pandas.core.series.Series' data type.

And that you can extract the value from the first row of a 'pandas.core.series.Series' with double brackets: `col[0]` or `counts[0]`

Nontheless indexes from `col` and `counts` are different. And this insight is what I think is the problem I'm about to present.

I have the next 'pandas.core.series.Series' data type generated by the next code:

We read the data frame as df

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

df has 'year' and 'product' columns, which I get its unique values and transform them into strings

```
vals_year = df['year'].astype('str').unique()
vals_product = df['product'].astype('str').unique()
```

This is the content in each variable:

```
>>>vals_year
>>>['16' '18' '17']

>>> vals_product  
>>>['card' 'cash']
```

Then I use the `value_counts()` method to count and create 'pandas.core.series.Series' data type :

```
cy = df['year'].value_counts()
cp = df['product'].value_counts()
```

This is the output:

```
>>>cy
>>>16  65
   17  40
   18  12
   Name: year, dtype: int64

>>>cp
>>>card  123
   cash  106
   Name: product, dtype: int64
```

Here is the first value of `cp`:

```
>>>cp[0]
>>>123
```

But when I try to see the first value from `cy` this happens:

```
>>>cy[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:.../Test3.py", line 44, in <module>
print(cr[0])
File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1064, in __getitem__
result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4723, in get_value
return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

(I just copy paste the message)

Why this happens? It makes no sense!! Is this a glitch in pandas? I believe the problem resides, as I said before, in the fact that The original values from `'year'` column were ints

Comment: it works for me, so not sure what's happening with you. Can you share the results of `cp.index[0]` and `cy.index[0]`?

Comment: Did you transform into strings the ints from `year`?

Comment: please don't answer my question with another question, that doesn't move the conversation forward.(I did both, string index and int index)

Comment: Yuca, I already realized wath is the problem. Which also should be a problem to you. when I tryed to check `cy[0]` it throwed an error because the indexes from cy are ints whose values are 16, 17 and 18. When I write `print(cy[16])` it throws the result `65`. I´m sorry for the trouble.

Comment: as I said, it works for me on both cases. So your problem is something else. Good luck!

Comment: try: 'cy.reset_index()' then call cy[0]